# SD cards get corrupted

Tags: microsd

I have an Ender 3 Pro 3D printer and a few months back I got a blue screen after printing something. I didn't even try to fix it because I got tired of running into problems.

Now I opened it again and everything seemed to work. I tried to open the SD card in my laptop to load a new 3D file but the laptop wouldn't even open with the card in it (I'm using a USB adapter with an SD card slot). I removed the card, opened the laptop, put the card in again and the system sees the card, but it won't let me do anything to it. I tried formatting it but I can't right-click on it because the window will freeze, the "Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions" tool in Windows 10 won't open either with the card in.

I tried grabbing a different card, put it in, loaded the prints and then tried running it in the printer, but the printed won't see this card. Going back to check on the laptop, this SD card has the same issue now.

Has anyone run into this problem or have any idea if I can recover the memory cards?

Comment: Just out of interest, are these branded SD cards, or cheap clones?

Comment: for the sds, try linux gparted. there are also some free disk imaging/formatting windows tools you can try.  printer is indeed the likely culprit so fix that before sticking more cards in it...

Comment: I've had difficulty with the CR-5 Pro not reading the cards. Sometimes it takes many tries at inserting the card. When the printer finally shows the "Print from TF" option, I am unable to select the gcode file I want. Turning the dial does not scroll through the files. I can't even re-flash the board. The card looks fine when I put it in my laptop. Does not seem corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of your issue:
*Your Ender 3 Pro 3D will repetitively and consistently corrupt multiple MicroSD cards that are inserted. Originally known working SD cards used in the printer are never recognized by it and once the card is used back at the computer it be unreadable and can't be formatted. Also that you have had a apparent LCD board issues in the past (dark screen)*

If your **confident to you're satisfaction** that this will happen every time with any computer/SD card/card adapter combination you try I see only couple options.

1. Consider seller warranty for replacement or parts, if this is not a option then read on.
2. Re-seat and inspect all electrical connections to and from all boards. Double check with official documentation that all connectors are in the correct spot. (with printer off)
3. Check with a multi meter the accuracy and stability of the 24 and 5 volt rails. This is a slight long shot but is easy to do and could save you from a lot of work. Use caution to not short any pins on the board when doing this on a powered board.
4. Re-Flashing the printer [Firmware](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/pages/firmware-download?gclid=CjwKCAjwpMOIBhBAEiwAy5M6YHJVMMkzpKIn2oBfzfhZK65iWBuYyIhcmHZjCHpSrxzapuPedAwuhxoCyIoQAvD_BwE)  might also be a useful thing to try.
5. Failing all that this will likely require a board replacement. However it's not clear to me if the Control Board or the LCD Board is the more likely the culprit. Due to proximity to the SD card and possible past issues I would lean towards the LCD Board.

Comment: Will try flashing the firmware again and see if it solves the issue. Thank you for your help!